# Как зафиксировать размеры окна в Java

Tags: java, swing

При использовании менеджера компоновки FlowLayout можно удобно разместить элементы интерфейса в заданных размерах фрейма. Однако, если в процессе работы программы пользователь захочет изменить размеры окна, то весь созданный вами дизайн поплывет. Как запретить пользователю менять размеры окна работающего приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для фиксирования размеров окна можно вызвать метод контейнера JFrame setResizable().

```
<имя_вашего_фрейма>.setResizable(false);
```

Comment: Вы можете отметить свой ответ как ответ на ваш вопрос, поставить галку)

Comment: хех) логично! Спасибо!